# GetManifestResourceStream returns null for an embedded resource with a verified resource name in GetManifestResourceNames

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I have a case where `GetManifestResourceStream` returns null for an embedded resource where the resource name is verified against `GetManifestResourceNames`.

- Embedded Resource files for a number of countries have been added to the project.
- The resource `Build Action` is "Embedded Resource".
- The resource name passed to `GetManifestResourceStream` exists in the list returned by `GetManifestResourceNames`. The resource name passed to `GetManifestResourceStream` comes from the list returned by `GetManifestResourceNames`.

My steps are:

- Obtain the qualified resource path.

  ```
  private string GetCountryResourcePath(string countryName)
  {
  Assembly assembly = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
  string[] assemblyResources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

  string searchTerm = string.Format(".{0}, countryName);

  foreach(string resourcePath in assemblyResources)
  {
      if (resourcePath.LastIndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)>0)
          return resourcePath;
  }
  return string.Empty;
  }
  ```
- If a resource path is found for the specified country, try to open with `GetManifestResourceStream`:

  ```
  string countryResourcePath = GetCountryResourcePath( countryName );
  if (countryResourcePath == String.Empty)
      return;

  using (Stream countryStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(countryStream))
  ...
  ```
- In my case, the countryName:"Russia.json" is used.
- `GetCountryResourcePath("Russia")` returns "Jfx.Data.Countries.Russia.json".
- `GetManifestResourceStream("Jfx.Data.Countries.Russia.json")` returns null.

Comment: `"Jfx.Data.Countries.json"` != `"Jfx.Data.Countries.Russia.json"`

Comment: Thanks for the catch - I have corrected the typo.